# Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I got the following error by running the test case:

> Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
>   This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

I ran the test case with `--ForceExit` as well as `--detectOpenHandles`. But I didn't resolve this error.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: @pathan, Thanks for responding.

test('Fetch Token ', async(done)=> {
        await getToken('DEV', 'myApp', (token) => {
            console.log("AuthToken: ",authToken);
            expect(authToken).toBeFalsy();
        });
        done();
    });

Comment: Please read SO help sections on how to ask questions. All relevant code must be embedded in the body of the question itself. Please edit your question to met SO guidelines. As is, it is subject to deletion from the SO platform.

Comment: Use --forceExit (with lowercase f) and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
test("Fetch Token ", async done => {
  await getToken("DEV", "myApp", token => {
    console.log("AuthToken: ", authToken);
    expect(authToken).toBeFalsy();
  });
  done();
});
```

2 possible reason:

- Your async request `getToken` used the wrong variable, instead of `authToken`, it's `token`.

```
test("Fetch Token ", async done => {
  await getToken("DEV", "myApp", token => {
    console.log("AuthToken: ", token);
    expect(token).toBeFalsy();
  });
  done();
});
```

- Your async request took too long to response, try to increase jest timeout `jest.setTimeout(5000)`

**suggestion**

When you use async-await you dont need to use done.

- with async-await

```js
test("Fetch Token ", async done => {
  const authToken = await getToken("DEV", "myApp", token => {
    return token;
  });
  console.log("AuthToken: ", authToken);
  expect(authToken).toBeFalsy();
  done();
});
```

- without async-await

```js
test("Fetch Token ", (done) => {
 getToken("DEV", "myApp", token => {
    console.log("AuthToken: ", token);
    expect(token).toBeFalsy();
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems your example "with async-await" uses "done" which is not allowed. What worked for me is --forceExit

Answer (score 1):

@johnson lai's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54318889/5411817) has a good explanation of how to ensure the asynchronous code is handled but, without seeing any of your code, it's hard to really find a solution for you.

I just spent a couple of hours dealing with this. The true problem is that if your test executes any other code that uses asynchronous code like a database connection, server, or anything similar, you need to mock it or ensure any connection is closed.

For me, I was testing an API endpoint that involved a server with NodeJS and a `pg` module database connection. Despite properly handling the asynchronous code in the test, the database and server connection isn't handled in the test and remains open after the test finishes.

The solution: I mocked the `pg` module and created a variable to reference the server instance. Then I did a setup and teardown with `beforeEach` and `afterEach` to create the server connection and close it for each test while the database was mocked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is any database/redis connection not closed.
2. Check if there is any timer not cleared.

Comment: While this is a good thing to look for, it seems that the call to `done()` is placed outside of the last operation, I assume the 3rd arguments of `getToken` is async as well. Can you try with 
test('Fetch Token ', async (done) => {
  await getToken('DEV', 'myApp', (token) => {
    console.log('AuthToken: ', authToken);
    expect(authToken).toBeFalsy();
    done();
  });
});

instead?